# Default constructor that resets dynamic array item

Tags: c++, oop

I need to implement constructor without parameters that will initialize items of dynamic array to zero. I thought make something like this:

```
MyType()
{
    p = new int[Size];
    for (int i = 0; i<Size; i++)
    {
        p[i] = 0;
    }
}
```

But I understand, that default constructor can't have any parameters to define its size. Moreover, later I need to input size of dynamic array from keyboard.
Is there any solutions?

Comment: So define a default size? I don't understand the problem

Comment: Since you don't have the size in the constructor, you can't allocate memory or initialize that. Just initialize the pointer `p` to `nullptr`, and allocate memory *when* you have the size.

Comment: It could be a template parameter, like std::array does.

Comment: Where is `Size` defined? Can you provide more context (more of your related code)?

Comment: Whenever you need a dynamic array in C++, just use `std::vector`

Comment: A default constructor either has no arguments, or has a set of arguments that are all given default values (at the point where the function is first declared - in the class definition).

Comment: Why do you need to use the default constructor? If you need to pass arguments to a constructor, it's pretty clear, that you don't want the default constructor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a `std::vector<int>` (which is a dynamic array) as member of your class. You don't actually need to initialize and it supports advanced concepts such as reserving memory.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector

Answer (score 0):

As was said, it's better to use `std::vector` instead of dynamic arrays, or you may try to play with [realloc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/realloc/) at your own risk.